How to add TextWrapping to multiple elements in a template
I am learning WPF and I have a problem. I am creating a custom control, inheriting it from TextBox. I want to add a placeholder to the TextBox. In the layout I am using 2 ScrollViewer elements, one of which is a placeholder, and the second is a normal text. The problem is that in TextWrapping is applied only to the main ScrollViewer element.
I looked at how Microsoft implements TextWrappint for TextBox, but I still couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.
Trigger-less template and C# code:
<Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_Placeholder" 
                Content="{TemplateBinding Placeholder}"
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderForeground}"
                FontSize="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderFontSize}"
                FontFamily="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderFontFamily}"
                FontWeight="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderFontWeight}"
                FontStyle="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderFontStyle}"
                FontStretch="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderFontStretch}"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                IsEnabled="False"
                Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
</Border>

public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceholderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Placeholder", typeof(string), typeof(ModifierTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
public string Placeholder
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
}

I'll clarify that I know that there are already many options to make a TextBox with placeholder, but I'm learning and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I haven't found similar questions on any of the forums.
